# New Cognito User Pool per function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Following the guide given at [Examples: Using the JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-signing-out), it has some descriptive examples, but doesn't explain much. If i had two functions that both used a userpool, could I use the same userpool object for them both?

```
function getUser() {
var data = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_Iqc12345',
    ClientId : '12345du353sm7khjj1q'
};
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(data);
var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

if (cognitoUser != null) {
    cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());
    });
}
```

and another function in the same file

```
function confirmUser() {
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
    ClientId : '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
};

var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Pool : userPool
};

var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.confirmRegistration('123456', true, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('call result: ' + result);
});
```

Could I create one userpool for the file and have anything in that file use that one userpool, or should this be created each time a new function needs access to it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with just creating one user pool object for both calls. The calls just use the information in the user pool object and don't update the state inside.